# Website updating from git (over ssh)

Tags: bash, ssh, git, webserver

I have a script that I run over SSH, which updates my website from a Git repo.

```
cd website-git
git checkout master
git pull

# Update protected directory
rsync -v -a --delete --exclude=db --exclude=vendor ./protected/ /home/protected

# Update public directory
rsync -v -a --delete --exclude=tmp --exclude=data ./public/ /home/public
```

It works fine, but the git repository has 150 MB and I pay for space used, so this is not a very good solution.

Apart from deleting the working copy (initially obtained with `git clone`) after taking the files form it, is there some way to save space with this setup?

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate how to use [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com) to deploy your PHP code instead of reinventing the wheel with a Bash script like this. Capistrano is basically a series of Ruby scripts that in-turn then run a series of Bash commands to deploy code from a code repository to a remote server.

Although Capistrano is mainly used in the Ruby development world, but I have used it on tons of PHP projects and it works great. [This is a nice tutorial](http://www.davegardner.me.uk/blog/2012/02/13/php-deployment-with-capistrano/) on how to adapt Capistrano for usage in PHP applications. Ditto [with this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-automate-php-app-deployment-process-using-capistrano-on-ubuntu-13).

If space is a concern, once you have your Capistrano scripts setup be sure to set the `:keep_releases` setting to something low like 2 or 3 like this in the Capistrano script:

```
set :keep_releases, 3
```