# Remote machines making unauthorized SSH login attempts

Tags: ssh, internet-security

I recently configured my external-facing router to forward traffic to port 22 on one machine on my LAN. SSHD is the only service listening on port 22.

Immediately I received traffic from IP addresses such as `36.156.24.97` and `223.111.139.210`, which according to IP identification websites, have tried to make unauthorized login attempts on thousands of different machines.

When I reviewed `/var/log/auth.log`, I saw entries saying that my machine `Received disconnect from 223.111.139.210`. I expected to see logs detailing failed login attempts, or more detailed information.

I am running Debian.

Does anyone have any conjectures regarding what those remote machines were trying to do?

Comment: While this other question is about WGET attempts, it is still—in my humble opinion—a possible duplicate of [Should I be concerned about hacking attempts via wget on a CentOS/LAMP-based web server?](https://superuser.com/questions/962940/should-i-be-concerned-about-hacking-attempts-via-wget-on-a-centos-lamp-based-web). The reality is any public-facing server will be probed fairly endlessly. You should not be worried. If you are concerned, then [follow the advice I post here](https://superuser.com/a/1036612/167207). In general, do not panic. You are not being targeted. This is normal.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any conjectures regarding what those remote machines were trying to do?

Attempting to connect to any open 22 port that'll take them and trying default/common credentials in order to gain access, most likely.

It's rarely a good idea to leave 22 open to the world. If you do, ensure you're taking security measures (whitelists/PKI/fail2ban/etc) and have a good reason to do so. Obfuscating your ssh port is useful, but not anything close to "secure", so pair that with the other measures if you must.